# Unable to load calibration file in uvc_camera over network

Tags: ros, camera-info-manager, network, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to launch a node over the network with the following code:

```
<node machine="$(arg machine)" name="uvc_camera_bsl12" pkg="uvc_camera" type="stereo_node">
<param name="left/device" value="$(arg ldev)" />
<param name="right/device" value="$(arg rdev)" />
<param name="left/camera_info_url" value="file://$(find baseline12)/data/camera_yaml/bsl12_left_01.yaml" />
<param name="right/camera_info_url" value="file://$(find baseline12)/data/camera_yaml/bsl12_right_01.yaml" />
<param name="fps" value="15" />
<param name="skip_frames" value="3" />
<param name="width" value="640" />
<param name="height" value="480" />
<param name="frame_id" value="baseline12" />
<param name="left/rotate" value="false" />
<param name="right/rotate" value="false" />
</node>
```

but it says

```
rectified topic '/baseline12/left/image_rect_color' requested but camera publishing '/baseline12/left/camera_info' is uncalibrated
```

It seems that it doesn't load .yaml file because $(find) command load local path instead remote path.

Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54184/unable-to-load-calibration-file-in-uvc_camera-over-network/) by [daddy1988](https://answers.ros.org/users/3970/daddy1988/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out a copy of the **baseline12** package on the remote machine.

It would be possible, but tricky, for camera_info_manager to support **http:** URLs directly. If you feel you need it, please [open an enhancement ticket](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_common/issues?state=open).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0